# Sort Individual Elements of a List

Tags: python

I am trying to sort the individual elements of a list, but not necessarily the entire list.

Given the following list

```
L = ['A,X,D' , 'Q,A' , 'A,C,B']
```

I want to sort the individual elements alphabetically giving so that it looks like the following

```
L = ['A,D,X' , 'A,Q', 'A,B,C']
```

I tried

```
L = sorted(L, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Why are you using comma-delimited strings of letters instead of, say, a `list`?

Comment: Hi, did my answer solved your problem? if so, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
L = [",".join(sorted(l.split(","))) for l in L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.split` with `sorted`:

```
L = ['A,X,D' , 'Q,A' , 'A,C,B']
new_l = [','.join(sorted(i.split(','))) for i in L]
```

Output:

```
['A,D,X', 'A,Q', 'A,B,C']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort each part of the list:

```py
L = ['A,X,D' , 'Q,A' , 'A,C,B']

L2 = [','.join(sorted(x.split(','))) for x in L]

L2
# ['A,D,X', 'A,Q', 'A,B,C']
```

If you don't use `split`, you will be sorting with commas included, which has a lower lexicographic value than alphabetical characters:

```py
sorted(L[0])
# ',', ',', 'A', 'D', 'X'
```

`join` will put the commas back in their original places

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort a *list of strings* based on each string.

First you need to convert the strings into list, like this:

```
list_of_lists = [l.split(',') for l in L]

output:
[['A', 'X', 'D'], ['Q', 'A'], ['A', 'C', 'B']]
```

Then, you want to sort each list:

```
sorted_lists = [sorted(l) for l in list_of_lists]

output:
[['A', 'D', 'X'], ['A', 'Q'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Now that we've sorted each list, we want to convert the inner lists back to string (we can use `join`):

```
list_of_strings = [','.join(l) for l in sorted_lists]

output:
['A,D,X', 'A,Q', 'A,B,C']
```

Or you can do it all in one line, like this:

```
sorted_strings = [','.join(sorted(l.split(','))) for l in L]

output:
['A,D,X', 'A,Q', 'A,B,C']
```